# MySQL If Statement in INSERT while SELECT from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get my query to insert a row into the database for each item in another database. I also want it to change the value of Unlocked if the ID of the other table is 1.

```
INSERT INTO tblPlayerCharacters (HottSourceID, CharacterID, Unlocked)
SELECT $hottSourceID, tblCharacters.ID, IF(tblCharacters.ID == 1, 0, 1)
FROM tblCharacters
```

Without the IF Statement it work fine if I didn't want the dynamic insert.

This is the error I am getting
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 1, 0, 1) FROM tblCharacters' at line 2

Comment: So, this doesn't work?  Do you see an error?  What does it insert?  What do you see if you just run the `SELECT` without the `INSERT`?

Comment: Without the IF statement its entering perfect. I just need to add the dynamic side of things. In the database nothing is being entered.

Comment: AFAIK, tests in mysql are done using only one `=`.

Comment: does the select portion work on its own?

Comment: This is all fixed, thanks guys. See below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't use double equal sign. Remove it and retry.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace :

```
IF(tblCharacters.ID == 1, 0, 1)
```

With :

```
IF(tblCharacters.ID = 1, 0, 1)
```